# Unusual meaning of "to play with"

Tags: word-meaning

I have been reading a book and found a meaning of the verb *to play with*, which is not in the dictionary, but I bet I've heard it couple of times before.

The context:

> Adam explained how, years ago they had played with genetics to try and ...

The meaning:

> to play with something = to experiment with something

Could the verb *to play with* be used having such a meaning?

Comment: It's in the dictionary, but not all dictionaries. So it is hardly an undiscovered" meaning. To "play with" means "to tinker (with)" and that can mean "to experiment (with)".

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

I'm not sure which dictionary you're using, but The American Heritage Dictionary of Phrasal Verbs lists that as definition #6 of *to play with*. The definitions are listed here:

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/play+with

Comment: Used *Macmillan English Dictionary*, my favourite. Thanks for pointing to another source!

Comment: @DenisK - Another great resource is [OneLook](http://www.onelook.com/?w=play&ls=a). Look up a word in OneLook and presto! Links to dozens of dictionaries for easy research. I'm also fond of [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/play), which pulls from around 4 or so dictionaries with every lookup.